# If $H, K \le G$ and $\ H \cap K \unlhd H$ and $K$ then how is $H \cap K \unlhd \langle H, K \rangle$?

Tags: group-theory

I want to show $H \cap K \unlhd \langle H, K \rangle$. I'm maybe missing something obvious, but how do you do this?

If $g \in \langle H, K \rangle$ is such that $g \in H$ or $K$, then it's easily seen that $g^{-1} (H \cap K) g = H \cap K$ because $H \cap K $is normal in both $H$ and $K$. But what if $g$ is something else not in either subgroups $H$ and $K$, how do you deal with that?

Comment: So you know that $H$ and $K$ are both contained in the normalizer $N_G(H \cap K)$ of the subgroup $H \cap K$ in $G$. Since the normalizer of a subgroup is itself a subgroup, this implies that $\langle H,K \rangle \le N_G(H \cap K)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there: Let $g \in \langle H,K \rangle$. Then $g$ can be written as a product of elements of $H$ and $K$, i.e. $g = a_1 \cdots a_n$, where $a_i \in H \cup K$ for all $i$. I assume now you can easily finish the proof, right?